# What is the limit for addresses in BCC in sendgrid using Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, smtp, bcc

I want to send out a marketing email to a little over 11,000 email addrresses using Outlook 2007 (could also be 2010) on an account configured to use the SendGrid SMTP server. what is the limit to the number of email adresses I can put into the BCC field before sendgrid will start complaining? Can I put all of them in there, or do I need to process them in batches? How big can the batches be?

Comment: There is no psychical limits but the more you send the larger the memory used so can fail, use a distribution list, only business contact manager has a limit of 1000

Comment: What's the point? Just send 11000 individual emails.

Comment: 11,000 individual mails without a tool? how do you suggest I do that in a timely fashion?

Comment: There is usually limits. I advise against this. Look up tarpitting. Nate, people send large mail shots over a period of time. For many good reasons. I've written mail shot software and dealt with it a lot, the point is if Server A receives X emails at once from you (although to different people), all with the same content, it could be seen as spam.

Comment: You could also bring the server to a grinding halt, causing it to time out/crash and then not know which emails did send or didn't. In one company, we sent 10 emails per 10 minutes, some mail shots took a few weeks to send. Why do you need them all to get the email in a timely manner? If there is a limited promotion period, start it early or increase the promotional period. You also need to consider (off topic) if you send all at once, can you cope with the responses

Comment: I don't want to send them individually (that question was more intended as a rhetorical one). I want to send them in as little batches as possible using the Sendgrid SMTP server on an Outlook 2007 client. I have done this before using this method in batches of 900 and it worked fine that time (and the time before with smaller batches). I want to know the maximum size of my batches. It's a pure marketing mail for a real estate project sent from a noreply address.

Comment: Fine, all I'm saying is your ISP may prevent emails going through if you hit their threshold (which they may or may not inform you about) and you run the changes of being black listed. Any way, I guess you could hit at least 500 based upon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825465/best-practices-for-sending-email-to-lots-of-recipients-rails-sendgrid

Comment: I already know I can send them out in at least batches of 900. i'm interested to know if I can send them out in, say, batches of 1500 or 2000, which would dramatically increase my processing speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from sendgrids documentation

> Customers should utilize SMTPAPI if this is an option. As with SMTP,
>   100 messages can be sent with each connection, but there can be 1000
>   recipients for each message.

reminding that the receiving end also has limits on how many mail addresses you can put on the to , cc and bcc fields